# Getting rid of all linebreaks in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pypdf

I have code that extracts text from several PDFs from [this website](https://covapp.vancouver.ca/councilMeetingPublic/CouncilMeetings.aspx?SearchType=3) using selenium and extracts the text into separate rows using PyPDF2.

When trying to export my Pandas dataframe to CSV for further analysis, most rows successfully save the text from each PDF into a single cell, but some of the text gets exported strangely into different cells. The problem starts at index 5 (row 7) as can be seen here:  [image]

I have tried several different cleaning steps but can't get the stubborn breaks to go away. Here's what ive tried for cleaning and getting the text together in one complete string:

```
import re
df['PDF_text'] = df['PDF_text'].str.replace('\n', '')

df['PDF_text'] = df['PDF_text'].str.replace('  ', '')

df['PDF_text'] = df['PDF_text'].str.replace('[™,ﬂŒ*]|;:^', '')

df['PDF_text'] = df['PDF_text'].str.replace('\r', '')
 
df['PDF_text'] = df['PDF_text'].str.replace('\t', '')

df['PDF_text'] = df['PDF_text'].str.replace('\v', '')

df['PDF_text'] = df['PDF_text'].str.replace('{,,â€š}', '')

# Send dataframe to csv for further analysis
df.to_csv('file_name.csv', encoding='utf-8', index='index')
```

The pandas dataframe looks like this: [image]

Any ideas what else I can try, or how to figure out what's causing the breaks into different cells. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe look into using regex where there's a whitespace-matching pattern: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: please show how the data in the dataframe looks like.

Comment: Hi @Mohammad, I added a picture of the dataframe from vs code data viewer. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @mobo1 yeah but this still doesn't show the problem. I wanted to see what is the content for index 5 for e.g.

Comment: Oh I see! Yes for index 5, the 'PDF_text' cell is all the pages from this PDF https://council.vancouver.ca/20210720/documents/regu20210720min.pdf appended together. The break seems to happen on page 16 of the PDF right after the line 'the floor space ratio (FSR)', but I can't figure out why

Comment: ahhh.. that is definitely what's happening. thank you so much!